# Why private, static, protected access modifers are not used with a class?

Tags: java

and why the same, can be used with inner classes?

```
public class Hello {
    class inner{ // this class can use any modifier
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is very vague. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: "illegal modifier for the class Hello; only public, abstract & final are permitted" - javadoc

Answer (score 7):

Java only allows top level classes / interfaces to be `public` or `package`.

[Section 7.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) states (Top Level Type Declarations):

> By default, the top level types declared in a `package` are accessible
>   only within the compilation units of that package, but a type may be
>   declared to be public to grant access to the type from code in other
>   packages (§6.6, §8.1.1, §9.1.1).

[Section 9.1.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html) of interface modifiers states:

> The access modifiers protected and private pertain **only** to member
>   interfaces within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration
>   (§8.5.1).
>
> The modifier `static` pertains only to member interfaces (§8.5.1, §9.5),
>   **not to top level interfaces** (§7.6).

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Private** top-level class does not make any sense because you can't access it from anywhere.

**Protected** means to access class within the same package or subclass of the outer class.Since there isn't package inheritance in java then protected classes also does not make any sense.

When we declare method/parameter as **static**, then we can access it without creating an instance of object.Because static member belongs to the class as a whole, not the instance of class or object. Since there isn't enclosing class for top-level classes, it is meaningless to define top-level classes as static.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes can be `static`, `private`, `protected`, package-local, or `public`

Top level classes are not;

- `static` as this wouldn't mean anything.  `static` for a nest class means it doesn't hold a reference to an outer class, but if you are the outer class it doesn't have a use.
- `private` classes cannot be access from another class file, so a private top level class couldn't be accessed.
- `protected` classes could potentially be used from sub classes, but making the class `abstract` is clearer. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

All types of **access** modifiers can be used on all types of `class`s (except anonymous classes).

Classes with other types of modifiers, will give access, exactly like a method.

`static` won't work, since it means that it belongs to some other class, that is never true for an outer class.

Comment: "illegal modifier for the class Hello; only public, abstract & final are permitted" - javadoc

Comment: @GoodManish - can you link me that _Javadoc_? default and private, are also permitted....